# How to avoid pjsua assertion failure on startup race condition?

Tags: pjsip, assertion

I am building an application with [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org), specifically the PJSUA component. Occasionally, if an incoming INVITE arrives during program startup, I will get the assertion failure

```
../src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_acc.c:2777: pjsua_acc_find_for_incoming: Assertion `pjsua_var.acc_cnt!=0' failed.
```

The `pjsua_acc_find_for_incoming` function is called unconditionally from `pjsua_call_on_incoming`, which is called from `mod_pjsua_on_rx_request` when an INVITE is received.

The problem arises because I am using `pjsua_acc_add_local`, which requires a `pjsua_transport_id`, which comes from `pjsua_transport_create`. The transport must therefore be created before the account can be added. If an INVITE arrives during the intervening time, this assertion will be triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem was due to calling `pjsua_init` and `pjsua_start` before adding the account with `pjsua_acc_add_local`. By switching the order of initialisation, so that `pjsua_acc_add_local` is called before `pjsua_init`, this problem is avoided. With the PJSUA module not running, there is no possibility of an INVITE arriving before the account is created.